# Guide to protect SQL Server against speculative execution side-channel vulnerabilities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am going through [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4073225/guidance-for-sql-server).  My question is regarding Scenario 1 under recommendation as most of our SQL Servers run on physical machine

> SQL Server runs on "bare metal" (no virtual machines)
>
> AND no other untrusted application logic (application tier) is run on
>   the same machine
>
> AND no untrusted SQL Server extensibility interfaces are being used
>   (see below for list).

What does it mean by untrusted application logic?

Does a webserver running on the same server with internally developed site constitute untrusted application logic?

What about a third party services that monitors the server?

Comment: The definition of "untrusted" is simply up to your judgement.  Assuming you trust Microsoft's software, if you trust your web developers and the website is using IIS, then the website is not untrusted.   Again, for the monitoring software--do you trust the developer?  If it's freeware that you downloaded from www.bobsmalware.com, then probably not, but if it's a major, reputable software developer, then probably.

Comment: Thanks @TonyHinkle, i was under the impression that the word "Trust" had some technical meaning in programming.  Something like the executionpolicy setting in powershell or clr secury.

Comment: @security - now you know, in programming, trusted not secure has no meaning at all :)

Comment: This is probably the most disturbing example of untrusted application logic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal Notice that antivirus companies was involved in this scam, and AFAIK Symantec was paid for lack of detection. Another example: latest Kaspersky scam.

Comment: It means you do not run programs on the SQL Server machine or Code inside SQL Server (triggers/functions) which might want to exploit the weakness.

Answer (score 1):

Untrusted application logic means any application or service running any logic that you(r organization) does not trust.

For your purpose, if you want to be lenient (potentially less secure) you can substitute "unauthorized" for "untrusted" - if the server is running any unauthorized code, it falls under that category.

If you want to be conservative (potentially more secure), assume all your servers run untrusted application logic and move on with that as a founding security assumption, applying the more secure recommendations to them.